# Paypal API: REST or CLASSIC?

Tags: node.js, paypal, recurring-billing

I have successfully registered a REST API app wth Paypal but I am not sure if this is what I need or I need to create a CLASSIC API app from the same screen.

So far I have been testing in the sandbox, and the credentials I have been using follow this pattern:

```
{
"user" : "a@a.com", 
"host" : "api.paypal.com",
"port": "",
"client_id" : "ID",
"client_secret": "SECRET",

"classicAPI": {
"username" : "paypal_api1.domain.com",
"password" : "PWD",
"signature" : "SIGNATURE",
"environment" : "production" 
}
};
```

What my code is trying to do is to create a subscription, calling the "SetExpressCheckout" and "CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile", but I get a "PaypalMissing token"error.

Am I doing it the right way, ie REST API and those credentials? Looks like since I'm using the ClassicAPI parameters shouldn't I be registering a CLASSIC app?

For clarification, I'm using NodeJs and this plugin https://www.npmjs.org/package/paypal-recurring

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Express Checkout specifically would be using the classic API.  I'd recommend sticking with that for now as the REST API is still very young and doesn't have all of the features tied in yet that the classic API provides.

Comment: Thank you. Does that mean that I need to create a CLASSIC API app and use whatever credentials I obtain for it? So far I created a REST API app and was using the credentials I got for it.

I managed to create the REST app straight away, however for the CLASSIC it seems that it needs to go through a reviewing process?

Many thanks for your help.

Comment: For the classic API's the App ID is only required when working with Adaptive Payments API's (Pay, Preapproval, Invoicing, etc.)  General API's like Express Checkout, Payments Pro, Transaction Details, Transaction Search, etc. do not require an App ID, but merely the username, password, and signature.  In most cases, though, Adaptive Payments apps are approved immediately just like REST.

Comment: Mainly I will be doing subscription payments: create, modify and cancelling them. Perhaps I don't even need an app then?
Thank you.

Comment: Nope, you won't need an app for that if you're just using the Recurring Payments API.